# Invalid `VideoRow.podspec` file: undefined method `join' for "TLPhotoPicker":String

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Im confused as to why this error is occuring when I try to create my own podfile

I am following this tutorial here

https://ronakshah.org/How-To-Make-A-Cocoapod-With-Dependencies/

However, when I try to run pod install for the last step it gives me this error

> Invalid `VideoRow.podspec` file: undefined method `join' for "TLPhotoPicker":String

```
    Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'VideoRow'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'Eureka row that allows us to take or select a video.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
This is an add-on to the many rows that are in the Eureka Community. This row will allow users to select a video from there library to export to a backend service of there choosing.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/VideoRow'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Smiller193' => 'shawn.miller@temple.edu' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/VideoRow.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
   s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/EurekaCommunity'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.1'

  s.source_files = 'VideoRow/Classes/**/*'
  s.platform = :ios, "10.0"
  s.dependency = 'TLPhotoPicker'
  s.dependency = 'Eureka'
  s.swift_version = '4.2'
end
```

This is my podspec

```
    use_frameworks!

target 'VideoRow_Example' do
  pod 'VideoRow', :path => '../'
  pod 'Eureka'
  pod 'TLPhotoPicker'
  target 'VideoRow_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths


  end
end
```

Both of these seem right but I get an error every time I try to run pod install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `=` in the dependency sequence.

Do `s.dependency 'TLPhotoPicker'`. Docs [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency).